# Adding new record using odata model

Tags: sapui5

My Model

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("../services/myexp.xsodata", false);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'data');
```

Now I want to add new record to this model. Simple code -

```
openUserCreateDialog: function(){ 
    var oUserCreateDialog = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog();
    var oSimpleForm1 = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
        maxContainerCols: 2,
        content:[
            new sap.ui.core.Title({text:"Create"}),
            new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"User"}),
            new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:""}),
            new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Date"}),
            new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:""}),
            new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Description"}),
            new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:""})
        ]
    });             
    oUserCreateDialog.addContent(oSimpleForm1);
    oUserCreateDialog.addButton(
        new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            text: "Submit", 
            press: function() {
                var content = oSimpleForm1.getContent();
                var oEntry = {};
                oEntry.User = content[2].getValue();
                oEntry.Date = content[4].getValue();
                oEntry.Description = content[6].getValue();

                sap.ui.getCore().getModel().create('data>/user', oEntry, null, function(){
                        oUserCreateDialog.close();
                        sap.ui.getCore().getModel().refresh();
                    },function(){
                        oUserCreateDialog.close();
                        alert("Create failed");
                    }
                );
            }
        })
    );
    oUserCreateDialog.open();
},
```

When I am submitting the form, It's throwing an error as-

```
Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.getCore(...).getModel(...).create is not a function
```

What is wrong with my code. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are setting the model as a named model but accessing the default model.

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'data');
```

The above code sets oModel with the name 'data' but while reading you are accessing the default model

```
 sap.ui.getCore().getModel().create('data>/user', oEntry, null, function(){
                        oUserCreateDialog.close();
                        sap.ui.getCore().getModel().refresh();
                    },function(){
                        oUserCreateDialog.close();
                        alert("Create failed");
                    }
                );
```

So while accessing the model call the named model

```
   sap.ui.getCore().getModel('data').create('/user', oEntry, null, function(){
                    oUserCreateDialog.close();
                    sap.ui.getCore('data').getModel().refresh();
                },function(){
                    oUserCreateDialog.close();
                    alert("Create failed");
                }
            );
```

and this will work.